# Android - Realm how to query by boolean

Tags: java, android, realm, android-database

I have started to use ´Realm´ and I cannot figure out how to get all the results with the value **equals to true**.

Take a look my code below:

Java Class

```
@RealmClass
public class Bookmark extends RealmObject {
    private java.lang.String IdBookMark;
    private boolean BookMarkActive;

    public String getIdBookMark() {
        return IdBookMark;
    }

    public void setIdBookMark(String idBookMark) {
        IdBookMark = idBookMark;
    }

    public boolean isBookMarkActive() {
        return BookMarkActive;
    }

    public void setBookMarkActive(boolean bookMarkActive) {
        BookMarkActive = bookMarkActive;
    }
}
```

Function:

```
private boolean AnyBookMark (){
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(getContext());
    RealmQuery<Bookmark> query = realm.where(Bookmark.class);
    query.contains("BookMarkActive","true");
    RealmResults<Bookmark> userBookmarks = query.findAll();
    return userBookmarks.isEmpty();
}
```

Error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                     Process: gon250.dublinbikes, PID: 2624
>                                                                     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field 'BookMarkActive': type
>   mismatch. Was STRING, expected BOOLEAN.
>                                                                         at io.realm.RealmQuery.getColumnIndices(RealmQuery.java:146)
>                                                                         at io.realm.RealmQuery.contains(RealmQuery.java:816)
>                                                                         at io.realm.RealmQuery.contains(RealmQuery.java:802)
>                                                                         at tabs.Tab2.AnyBookMark(Tab2.java:55)
>                                                                         at tabs.Tab2.onCreateView(Tab2.java:33)

Version:

> compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.78.0'

What is the proper way to get all the results with `BookMarkActive` equals to `true`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `query.contains("BookMarkActive","true");` you can do `query.equalTo("BookMarkActive", true);`.

Btw, 0.78.0 is a really old version. I recommend that you upgrade soon ;-)

Comment: I can't do it.. I get an error because the bool. I have changed my object class so `BookMarkActive` is now a string and is working. Maybe is because the version isnt it? in case I update the Realm, Have I to change my code?

Comment: Updating to for example 0.87 will require changes to your code as we have changed the API and will do so until 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Function should be something like this:

```
private boolean anyBookMark() {
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(getContext());
    RealmQuery<Bookmark> query = realm.where(Bookmark.class);
    query.equalTo("BookMarkActive", "true");
    RealmResults<Bookmark> userBookmarks = query.findAll();
    return userBookmarks.isEmpty();
}
```

BookMarkActive column should be String type. If it is some other type then corresponding value should be passed rather that "true"